# Criar um SELECT para trazer a diferença de duas tabelas

Tags: php, sql

Tem a tabela `bisemanas` que armazena 26 bi-semanas fixas e a tabela `outdoor_bisemanas` que armazena as reservas dos *outdoors* conforme a bi-semana escolhida.

**Edit**: O que quero é um `select` que exiba todas as bi-semanas da tabela `bisemanas` que não estão cadastradas na tabela `outdoor_bisemanas` de cada outdoor. Ou seja quando eu selecionar um outdoor, quero que o SELECT traga todas as bisemanas que não estão cadastradas na tabela outdoor_bisemanas com o id do outdoor selecionado.

Este `SELECT` que fiz esta trazendo a diferença entre as bi-semana e cada bi-semana cadastrada em `outdoor_bisemanas` separadamente.

```
SELECT b.id_bisemanas
      ,b.data_inicio
      ,b.data_fim
      ,o.id_outdoor
  FROM bisemanas AS b
 INNER JOIN outdoor_bisemanas AS ob
    ON b.id_bisemanas != ob.id_bisemanas
 INNER JOIN outdoor AS o
    ON o.id_outdoor = ob.id_outdoor
 WHERE b.ano = '2017' && b.data_inicio BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() 
   AND '2017-12-31' &&  ob.id_outdoor = '1'
 GROUP BY b.id_bisemanas
```

---

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE bisemanas (
id_bisemanas INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ano INT(4) NOT NULL,
nome_bi VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
data_inicio DATE,
data_fim DATE
)

CREATE TABLE outdoor_bisemanas (
id_bisemanas INT(11) PRIMARY KEY,
id_outdoor INT(11) NOT NULL,
id_usuario INT(11) NOT NULL,
valor_total float,
FOREIGN KEY (id_bisemanas) REFERENCES bisemanas(id_bisemanas)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para trazer todas as bisemanas que não estão vinculadas a nenhum outdoor, o select abaixo faz isso:

```
SELECT *
  FROM bisemanas bs
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM outdoor_bisemanas obs
         WHERE bs.id_bisemanas = obs.id_bisemanas);
```

ou

```
SELECT *
  FROM bisemanas bs
  LEFT JOIN outdoor_bisemanas obs
    ON bs.id_bisemanas = obs.id_bisemanas
 WHERE obs.id_bisemanas IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para esta query, você precisa selecionar todos registros da tabela `bisemanas`, fazer um `LEFT JOIN` com a tabela `outdoor_bisemanas` e filtrar apenas pelos registros onde a chave primária da tabela `outdoor_bisemanas` retornou `NULL`, pois indica que o `JOIN` não casou com linha alguma. Exemplo:

```
SELECT b.*
  FROM bisemanas AS b
  LEFT JOIN outdoor_bisemanas AS ob
    ON b.id_bisemanas = ob.id_bisemanas
 WHERE (ob.id_bisemanas IS NULL);
```

Fiddle com o exemplo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jdJBAv51ssSd9WAFWAjHDd/0

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tente isto:

```
SELECT [ campos ]
  FROM bisemanas b
  LEFT JOIN outdoor_bisemanas o
    ON b.id_bisemanas = o.id_bisemanas
 WHERE o.id_bisemanas IS NULL
```

Abraço,

Answer (score 0):

A resposta que procurava era essa:

```
SELECT o.id_endereco,CONCAT(o.id_outdoor,'-',b.id_bisemanas) as chave FROM outdoor as o,bisemanas as b WHERE CONCAT(o.id_outdoor,'-',b.id_bisemanas) NOT IN(SELECT CONCAT(ob.id_outdoor,'-',ob.id_bisemanas) as chave FROM outdoor_bisemanas as ob) ORDER BY `chave` ASC
```